# jquery access form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, element

I wonder how to access forms elements which clicked button in any form.

```
<form action="">
   <textarea>Value1</textarea>
   <input type='submit'>
</form>
<form action="">
   <textarea>Value2</textarea>
   <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

What I need is; if I click first button; alert must be Value1, if I click second button; alert must be Value2. How can I do this?
There will be many form like this, so I cannot give id or name to every text.

Comment: show us what you have tried?

Comment: did you write a click handler... please share that

Comment: I tried childs of parent and siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code you can find a textarea in parent form of submit button:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find('textarea').val())
})
```

[Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BZJYj/](http://jsfiddle.net/BZJYj/)

Comment: But if you will change the layout of form like putting submit in other form child element, this code will not be right.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _clickEvent = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var value = $(this).closest('form').find('textarea').val();
     alert(value);
};

$('body').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', _clickEvent);
```